# Cannot make Bootstrap navbar transparent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to make my navbar transparent but so far nothing has worked for me. Can someone teach me how to do it? I assume it has something to do with the space that it is taking up in regards to the body content, but I am not sure what can be done as I have already tried reversing the div tags to be outside of the body.

This is my desired result : [image]

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zr1qh780/

My HTML :

```
<body>
  <div id="container">
      <!-- Navigation menu -->
    <header>
      <nav class="my-nav navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
         target="#navbarsExample08" aria-controls="navbarsExample08" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
         label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center" id="navbarsExample08">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="index.html" id="dropdown08" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
               haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">ACTIVITÉS</a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown08">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="rafting.html">Rafting</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="canyoning.html">Canyoning</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="saut-parachute.html">Saut en parachute</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="soufflerie.html">Simulation de chute libre</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="saut-elastique.html">Saut à l’élastique</a>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">OFFRES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ÉVÉNEMENTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">À PROPOS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">ESPACE HANDICAP</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link contact" href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="hamburger">
        <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;color: white;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
      </div>
      </nav>
      
    </header>

    <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <div class="bar overlay-content">
        <a href="#">ACTIVITÉS</a>
        <a href="#">OFFRES</a>
        <a href="#">ÉVÉNEMENTS</a>
        <a href="#">À PROPOS</a>
        <a href="#">ESPACE HANDICAP</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS:

```
    .logo { 
      margin-right:5px;
    }
    
    .my-nav{
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      padding: 8px;
      }
    
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
      color: white;
    }
    
    .navbar-nav > li {
        padding-left:25px;
        padding-right:45px;
        float:none;
        display:table-cell;
        text-align:center;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
      color: #fc3218;
    }
    
    .nav-link:active { 
      color: #fc3218;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      background: grey
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu {
      color: white;
      background-color: #fc3218;
    }
    
    .dropdown-item { 
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .navbar-collapse {
      flex-grow: 0.3;
     
    }
```

Comment: You need to make the background of the nav element transparent, correct?

Comment: Yes so that an image can be put over it. Here is the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/zr1qh780/)

Comment: what do you mean with `so that an image can be put over it` why not using a background image below it instead of covering the navbar with an image and make links unclickable?

Comment: Perhaps I explained myself wrongly, i uploaded a picture to my post of my desired result, can you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
navbar{
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

If that doesn't work, add `!important` to break the predefined bootstrap styles

Comment: Yes I have tried doing that, it has turned the navbar opaque in color but I still cannot overlap my image on top of it as the navbar itself is taking a static place on top.

Comment: Set .navbar to position:absolute

Comment: it works but moves my navbar to the inside of my lateral sidebar

Answer (score -3):

Set the **opacity** of the container for `nav bar` to **0**.

**Note**: Place the elements of `nav bar` in different `div` otherwise the text in `nav bar` will also get effected.

Comment: This won't work, because it will affect all children hanging from .navbar

Comment: opacity is rendered last. means it will effect the children aswell and be put above everything. Links will become unclickable and therefor be broken. Please delete your anwser as it only causes harm without being a solution.